# Grails: How to prepopulate data in-memory database and tear down

Tags: database, grails

Can anyone please share their experience on how to setup initial data in the in-memory H2 database:

```
dataSource {
    dbCreate = "create-drop" // one of 'create', 'create-drop', 'update', 'validate', ''
    url = "jdbc:h2:mem:devDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE"
}
```

When running "run-app" and tear down when stop the app and start fresh again?

Mainly I need to deal with username, password(encrypted) and some items data.

Comment: The h2 database is all in the memory, if you wish to initialise pre-existing values then look at BootStrap.groovy - where you can add entries to pre-populate the DB upon app start

Comment: cool, it works, thanks! I got a follow-up question though, i got some optional field, when i put empty string in BootStrap.groovy, i got the following error: "on field 'description': rejected value [null];", is there a way to resolve it without setting "nullable: true" in domain class?

Comment: absolutely https://github.com/vahidhedayati/jssh/blob/master/grails-app/domain/grails/plugin/jssh/SshServers.groovy#L14 as an example

Comment: Thanks. I actually found another way. put the below in Config.groovy. By this i won't impact the prod environment to avoid any unforeseen security issue by disable the null filter.

environments {
    development {
  //Disable convert empty strings to null for bootstrap.groovy purpose
  grails.databinding.convertEmptyStringsToNull = false
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that kind of configuration on grails-app/conf/BootStrap.groovy This code is executed every time that the app is started.

```
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        if(Environment.current == Environment.DEVELOPMENT) {
            def user = new User(...)
            user.save(flush: true)      
        }
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

Also with your configuration

```
dbCreate = 'create-drop'
```

You are creating and destroying the database each time.

Comment: Thanks. Your answer same with what Vahid provided above. It does work. But now i have another issue, i got several optional fields, when i define the value as empty string, i got "on field 'description': rejected value [null];". I try to avoid changing the domain class's field to "nullable:true", any way to get around this?

Comment: Setting the field as 'nullable:true' is exactly the solution. By default every field is not null so if you want to make it nullable you must add that. If that field is not represented as a column in the database the solution is to add it as a transient field.